# Problem between IE and FF testing a login

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir

This is so simple that I am stunned it is failing.  I am testing a very simply login sequence and essentially my code does this:

```
require "watir"
user = "allqax+beta1@gmail.com"
pswd = "qwerty"
br = Watir::Browser.new
br.goto("http://mysite.com")
br.link(:id,"login-menu").click                  # click the login menu
br.text_field(:id,"login-popup-user").set(user)  # enter the username 
br.text_field(:id,"login-popup-pswd").set(pswd)  # enter the password
br.link(:id,"login-popup-signin-button").click   # click the submit link
```

When I run this (which runs it in IE), it works fine.

When I add the following line right after the "require" statement:

```
Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
```

it now goes to Firefox 3.6, but when it enters the username, it only types in the first 8-12 characters and then stops.  As a result, the login fails ("invalid email address" is the most common message).

I also tried changing this to use FireWatir but it failed in precisely the same way.

Any ideas?  HELP! (And thanks so much in advance!)

Best regards,

Jon Rosen

***"Sometimes you're the pinball wizard, and sometimes, you're just the pinball."***

Comment: Just to clarify,
  Watir::Browser.default = "firefox"
Means use FireWatir, so that is why the result is the same.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide us with a script we can run that to reproduce the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me. I have similar code that works with both Firefox and IE. It is possible that you are running into a javascript issue with the particular page you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Watir works with IE through OLE protocol. That is it cannot work the same way with Firefox. You need firewatir gem to test with Firefox.
2. I didn't have much experience with firewatir. There were synchronization problems with browser. I may guess you have the same sync problems.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
br.text_field(:id,"login-popup-user").value=(user)
br.text_field(:id,"login-popup-pswd").value=(pswd)
```